# Conditional redirect to several pages

Tags: redirect

Suppose I have these WordPress pages:

- `page-A`
- `page-B`
- `page-C`

and a published page `page-main`.

**My question:**

The clients see and access only `page-main` which is in the end *virtual* - it doesn't exist. Accessing this `page-main` page should redirect to **one** of the above mentioned pages A-C, depending on some conditions which are not important for this question.
How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need this to happen before Wordpress has output anything at all, otherwise you won't be able to send a redirect.

A way to achieve this is with the `template_redirect` hook, documented here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect

The example from that docs page is more or less exactly what you want. I've edited it a little bit for your  question:

```
function my_page_template_redirect() {
    if ( is_page( 'page-main' ) ) {
        if ( $some_condition ) {
            wp_redirect( home_url( $pageA ) );
        } else { 
           ... other caeses here with redirects to other pages
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_page_template_redirect' );
```

You'd need to add that to your functions.php or a plugin.

Comment: Unfortunately this works only as long `page-main` does physically exists as a WordPress page. If `page-main` doesn't exist then `is_page()` doesn't trigger. Any idea or should I create a _dummy_ page with the name `page-main`.

Comment: I upvoted and accepted your answer as it works. I create a dummy `page-main` in order `is_page()` triggers. May be you have a solution when `page-main` doesn't exist but it's not that important. THX!

Comment: @PeterVARGA I've been meaning to find how to do this for sometime. I'll figure it out and update the answer